# systemd makes both fstab and manual mount fail

Tags: systemd, mount

Description:    Linux Mint 19.3 Tricia
Release:    19.3
Codename:   tricia
Kernel:         5.4.0-81-generic

An external USB disk became full and rsnapshot backup failed.
The disk was replaced by a bigger one and UUID updated at `/etc/fstab`.
Mounting from fstab failed silently.
Found a description of a similar problem [Why is mount failing silently for me?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459950/why-is-mount-failing-silently-for-me)

The latest is that I'm able to manually mount the drive correctly on command line if I each time run "`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`" and `/etc/fstab` will succeed as well.
It I umount the drive and try again, still the same i.e. "`sudo systemctl daemon-reload`" is always required prior to mounting.

I have found no way to make that `/etc/fstab` mounting work at boot time.
As described earlier in the reference above, apparently systems umounts the drive erroneously assuming the drive is still faulty even though it is not.

How to fix the situation?

Comment: Looking through all the comments in the 5 year old still-open systemd [issue](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/1741) seems to hint you might try unmounting the drive, removing the entry from /etc/fstab, doing the daemon-reload, "waiting a bit", perhaps doing `udevadm settle`, then putting back the entry, doing daemon-reload again, and trying a mount/umoun/mount to see if it stays mounted after the 2nd try! I sympathise.