# Mount fails silently - how to debug and fix?

Tags: systemd, mount

I have a(n MD) device `/dev/md1` with an ext2 for `/boot`. However, I cannot mount it at `/boot` (where is belongs):

```
# mount | grep boot
Exit 1
# mount | grep md1
Exit 1

# fsck /dev/md1
fsck from util-linux 2.23.2
e2fsck 1.42.9 (28-Dec-2013)
/dev/md1: clean, 362/40960 files, 121097/163696 blocks

# mount -v /dev/md1 /boot
mount: /dev/md1 mounted on /boot.
# ll /boot/
total 0
# umount -v /boot
umount: /boot: not mounted
# umount /dev/md1
umount: /dev/md1: not mounted
```

Mounting the device elsewhere works:

```
# ll /mnt/tmp/ | wc 
      1       2       8
# mount -v /dev/md1 /mnt/tmp
mount: /dev/md1 mounted on /mnt/tmp.
# ll /mnt/tmp/ | wc 
     35     308    2811
# umount /mnt/tmp
umount: /mnt/tmp (/dev/md1) unmounted
umount: /mnt/tmp: not mounted
Exit 32
```

What could be the issue?

UPDATE after seeing [this similar Question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/459950/why-is-mount-failing-silently-for-me): Something is umounting our partition right away:

```
# mount -v /dev/md1 /boot ; ll /boot/ | wc; sleep 0.1; ll /boot/| wc 
mount: /dev/md1 mounted on /boot.
     35     308    2811
      1       2       8
```

`systemd` could be umounting in the background.  I still don't know what to do.  `systemctl daemon-reload` did not help. `systemctl status` does not contain strings `/boot` or `mount`.

UPDATE 2:

```
# systemctl list-unit-files -t mount
UNIT FILE                     STATE   
dev-hugepages.mount           static  
dev-mqueue.mount              static  
proc-fs-nfsd.mount            static  
proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount static  
sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount static  
sys-kernel-config.mount       static  
sys-kernel-debug.mount        static  
tmp.mount                     disabled
var-lib-nfs-rpc_pipefs.mount  static  

9 unit files listed.
```

So, nothing here about `boot`.  However, there is a hidden (to me, thus far) `boot.mount` unit:

```
# journalctl -u boot.mount | filter-lines-by-hand
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3069]: umount: /boot: target is busy.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3069]: (In some cases useful info about processes that use
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3069]: the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: boot.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /boot.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3071]: umount: /boot: target is busy.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3071]: (In some cases useful info about processes that use
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3071]: the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: boot.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /boot.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3073]: umount: /boot: target is busy.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3073]: (In some cases useful info about processes that use
Jan 12 09:57:46 server umount[3073]: the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: boot.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Failed unmounting /boot.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
Jan 12 09:57:46 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount entered failed state.
```

So, yes, it is `systemd` umounting my `/boot` partition silently and annoyingly.  Wonder how `systemd` "thinks" updates should work without that mount.

Can I revive that?

```
# systemctl restart boot.mount
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
(approx. 2 minute wait)
A dependency job for boot.mount failed. See 'journalctl -xe' for details.
Exit 1

# journalctl -u boot.mount | tail -2
Jan 12 10:07:26 server systemd[1]: Dependency failed for /boot.
Jan 12 10:07:26 server systemd[1]: Job boot.mount/start failed with result 'dependency'.
```

And indeed, `journalctl -xe` has the message

```
Unit dev-md-1.device has failed.
```

So, the only question that remains is, how can I tell `systemd` to understand that md1 is actually doing just fine? This is a server so I do not want to reboot.

UPDATE 3:

Trying to teach systemd that the md1 device is actually quite well:

```
# systemctl reset-failed dev-md-1.device
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
# systemctl reset-failed \*
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
# mount -v /dev/md1 /boot ; ll /boot/ | wc ; sleep 0.1 ; ll /boot/ | wc
mount: /dev/md1 mounted on /boot.
     35     308    2811
      1       2       8
```

Not successful. It goes into fail right again.

```
# systemctl start dev-md-1.device
Authorization not available. Check if polkit service is running or see debug message for more information.
(approx. 2 minute wait)
Job for dev-md-1.device timed out.
Exit 1
# journalctl -u boot.mount | tail -4
Jan 12 15:19:19 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping, too.
Jan 12 15:19:19 server systemd[1]: Unmounting /boot...
Jan 12 15:19:19 server systemd[1]: Unmounted /boot.
Jan 12 15:19:19 server systemd[1]: Unit boot.mount entered failed state.
```

WORKAROUND:

```
# mount /dev/md1 /boot ; cd /boot ; nohup sleep 99000h < /dev/null > & /dev/null &
```

This will start a process with `/boot` as a CWD so that `systemd` cannot umount `/boot` due to the device being busy.  However, `systemd` creates > 18000 lines of error message in the journal per minute:

```
# journalctl -u boot.mount | fgrep 15:28: | awk '{ print $6 " " $7 " " $8 " " $9 " " $10 " " $11 " " $12 " " $13 " " $14 }' | sort | uniq --count
   1054 boot.mount mount process exited, code=exited status=32   
   4502 Failed unmounting /boot.      
   1792 (In some cases useful info about processes that use
   3279 the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1)) 
   5277 umount: /boot: target is busy.    
   1053 Unit boot.mount is bound to inactive unit dev-md-1.device. Stopping,
   1053 Unmounting /boot...
```

These are the counts of identical lines only for one minute!

Comment: What's the `Exit 1` at the top of your examples?

Comment: @ChrisDavies I use the `tcsh` and have `set printexitvalue` in `~/.cshrc`.  This means the shell shows non-zero exit codes of programs I call from the shell.

Comment: Ah! Thanks for that, Ned64

Answer (score 1):

To troubleshoot the issue:

1. list all the unit files of type "mount" on your system:

   **systemctl list-unit-files -t mount**
2. look for something like "boot.mount"
3. monitor your unit in the journal

   **journalctl -u boot.mount -f**
4. try to mount the filesystem

Comment: That did indeed reveal the hidden `boot.mount` unit failing, thanks. Added some details above. Do you also know how to revive the md1 unit without a reboot? My problem is that these aren't explicit `systemd` units and are therefore hidden from me.

Comment: You might try `systemctl reset-failed dev-md-1.device` or just generally `systemctl reset-failed *` or any glob pattern.

Comment: Thanks @meuh added that to my Question, had no effect :-(

Comment: Remember to run `systemctl daemon-reload` after any changes to unit files or `/etc/fstab`.